# Browsing for All Bonjour services

Tags: python, bonjour

I want to write a python program which browses for all existing Bonjour services in my local network. And I ask if there is some way to do it since services come and go all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably begin by taking a look at existing libraries, such as [pybonjour](http://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/).

In principle, of course it's possible but you need to be prepared that a service might go away, and you will also need to refresh the idea of available servers to prevent it from going stale and not showing newly added ones.

There's example code on pybonjour's front page that shows how to browse for services.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to tell you that I am using the library "bonjour". I ask if it's a good idea if I search for all existing services for a specific period of time?